# Optimize single dumbbell routine?

Tags: workout-routines, routine

Hi fellow fitness enthusiasts and personal trainers.

Thanks to my gym closing down and me moving, I'll need to train at least 6 months without a gym.

At home I have a 15kg dumbbell. Since I'm not very strong, this will be enough at least for biceps, triceps and shoulders.

This is my routine I'm using now (all using just this one dumbbell)

> Biceps:    Sitting biceps curl    Standing biceps curl    Hammer curl
>
> Triceps:    Overhead push
>
> Shoulders:    Lateral raise    Front raise    Dumbbell shoulder press 
>   Back fly
>
> Chest:    One arm chest press
>
> Back:    Back row

In this exact order. Not training legs because I'm running and cycling quite a lot.

Do you have any tips to optimalize this routine/things I'm doing wrong?

My goal is muscle growth and I was wondering if I could achieve this with this routine?

Comment: Can you buy some more equipment from the closing gym?

Comment: @Noumenon Not sure, I'll check with them tomorrow

Comment: @Noumenon not with my budget :/ I'm still a student haha, I might be able to afford another dumbbell but only if you guys think it's worth investing in

Comment: I'd look into possibly getting a kettlebell or another dumbbell (that's heavier than your current one, maybe around 30kg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly the answer you are hoping for but the following resource could prove very useful: https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness

You can get some significant strength gains using just your bodyweight and very basic playground style equipment (bars/boxes).

If you are set on using a dumbbell here is a resource that gives you more options: http://dumbbell-exercises.com/